# Is there a Web browser extension to isolate or delete page elements?

Tags: web-browser, browser-extension

Many years ago, I remember I had found a Web browser extension which allowed you to go on a visual edit mode on a page, highlighting the different elements as you hovered over them, and allowing you to press different keys for different operations, for example 'd' to delete an element, 'i' to isolate the element (i.e. remove everything around it), and so on. I think it was called a hackbar or something like this, but I don't remember and I cannot find it anymore. The changes were not permanent of course, but they were enough to allow you e.g. to print an article without the ads, links, and other stuff around it (I know there are reader-mode extensions, that's not the point here).

Does it still exist? Any ideas?

UPDATE: after a long search, I found this one which is the closest I can get to my requirements, but it's still not the extension I had in mind. Maybe that extension is no longer maintained, but at least this will give you an idea of what I'm looking for:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/print-edit-we/olnblpmehglpcallpnbgmikjblmkopia

Comment: A limited form of this capability exists in Chrome and Edge without any extensions. Right-click on the element you're interested in. and select "inspect" from the menu.

Comment: I am also aware of this, thank you, I'm a developer. It's much easier to just hover over the page and press a key to act on elements interactively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean "Aardvark".
This was once a Firefox extension (?) but it is now a [Firefox bookmarklet](https://www.karmatics.com/aardvark/). For Chrome there is an Extension, [Aardvark2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aardvark2/llhafclbgkllflaighanjpidabbdbiim).

Comment: Yes, *YES*! That's it! Thank you! ️

Comment: Looks like the Firefox bookmarklet doesn't work any more, but the Chrome extension does the job (although looks a bit dated of course) 

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be looking for something like [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) and [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/). For chrome and Firefox respectively. Both allow client side DOM manipulation, so you can import things like jquery, search/find things, alter their attributes, and change the look/feel of the DOM as represented.

Long ago when I had a facebook, it looked more like a twitter feed, single column of posts, and all that other jazz just stripped out.

The do not have the direct hover/click function, but they DO allow you to target an item say with chrome dev tools, uniquely identify it, and then script to make it go bye, or move it, or alter its size, other css attributes, imagination is the only limit.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of those as well, it was another extension.

Comment: I have updated my question with an extension that comes the closest to what I'm looking for.